# USA transit visa without e-passport

Tags: visas, usa, transit

I will be transiting in Miami this July, on my way to Colombia. I am Polish national with a Polish passport, however my passport does not have the Echip so is not an electronic passport. Poland is also not part of the visa waiver programme countries, therefore I am applying for a C1 transit visa. 
I have been reading that all passengers to the USA are required to have an electronic passport. However I am unsure whether this is just for those people applying on the visa waiver programme or everyone (including all visa)? Again, I will be getting the c1 transit visa so is it ok to travel in the C1 without an electronic visa?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The e-passport requirement applies only to travelers who seek entry under the Visa Waiver Program.

Travelers who apply for (and are granted) a visa in advance do not need to have electronic passports. So you should be fine.